# JQuery $(function).animate is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I'm setting a button to scroll my page to a specific ID. However, the console always shows this error:

> $(.…).animate is not a function

Instead of scrolling, it jumps to the registered ID.

I've seen many posts about this problem, but all of them are providing me with a piece of information to change my `jQuery` version into full one instead of slim. But right now, I'm using the full version of `jQuery 3.4.1`.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#intro-scroller").click(function() {
    $(document).animate({
      scrollTop: $("#intro")
    }, 2000);
  });

  $("#about-scroller").click(function() {
    $(document).animate({
      scrollTop: $("#aboutme")
    }, 2000);
  });

  $("#education-scroller").click(function() {
    $(document).animate({
      scrollTop: $("#education")
    }, 2000);
  });

  $("#skill-scroller").click(function() {
    $(document).animate({
      scrollTop: $("#skill")
    }, 2000);
  });

  $("#project-scroller").click(function() {
    $(document).animate({
      scrollTop: $("#project")
    }, 2000);
  });

  $("#contact-scroller").click(function() {
    $(document).animate({
      scrollTop: $("#contact")
    }, 2000);
  });
})

require('./bootstrap');

// Jquery & JS
require('./jquery-3.4.1');
require('./jQuery-Progress-Bar-Plugin-LineProgressbar/jquery.lineProgressbar');
require('./ResponsiveSlides/responsiveslides');
require('./smoothscroll');
```

I expect that my jQuery `animate()` functions correctly, but the actual result is that my `animate()` function is treated as a non-function code.  It always returns `$(.…).animate is not a function` in the console.

Comment: The error implies that you're using the 'slim' branch of jQuery which does not contain animation or AJAX methods. If so you need to use the full version

Comment: Can you share the source of the jQuery you're using (in jsfiddle or similar)

Comment: @BrettGregson Here's the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/36rgcesx/

Comment: Where did you get that version from? It seems to be a much smaller file than the full jQuery 3.4.1

Comment: @BrettGregson I got that jQuery when creating new project on it

Comment: I mean where did you download it from?

Comment: @BrettGregson I downloaded it from jquery.com

Comment: Try replace it with this: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js

Comment: @BrettGregson I use both compressed and uncompressed version and still didn't work

Comment: @Greninja573 here's an example with animate working using that exact version of jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/3f0cypzx/ . Are you trying to make the page scroll to the top? Try use html or body instead of document

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `jquery` link before `app.js`.

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: If that was the problem the error would say `$ is not a function`

Comment: Now the error is TypeError: (intermediate value).style is undefined that references to the jQuery-3.4.1.min.js